# ASP.net MVC3 save last page a user viewed to display when they return to site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session, redirect, cookies

My site uses Windows Live to authenticate users.  The problem with this is that they are redirected away from the site to log in, and then back to my own SignIn action, which registers/signs in the user to my site.  Then by default I have the SignIn action redirecting to the user's profile page.

But what I want instead is for the SignIn action to return them the last page they viewed.  This seems like it should be simple.

My first thought was to add the following to my important actions to save the user's current place:

```
Session["LastPage"] = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Then at the end of my SignIn action I tried to include:

```
if (Session["LastPage"] != null)
    return (ActionResult)Session["LastPage"];
else
    return RedirectToAction("MyPage", "User");
```

This doesn't actually work though, since apparently my session is getting restarted every time the user navigates away from and back to the site.

Am I approaching this issue the right way?  If so, how do I keep the session from getting wiped?  If I'm going about this completely the wrong way, then can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ReturnUrl property of WindowsLiveLogin object (assuming you're using one).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287661.aspx

Comment: Wrong for two reasons: (1) the response from WL needs to be processed by my SignIn action, so I must always visit that first, (2) you cannot dynamically assign redirect urls to Windows Live, the redirect URL is fixed and has to match what you provided in your application's settings on their site.